# ssl.SSLHandshakeException occurs when try to read xml from URL

Tags: java, android

I got SSLHandshakeException when try to read XML from URL.
The error happens in this line:
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

```
    protected LinearLayout doInBackground(String... string) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(DevicesActivity.this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);
        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */ 
        TextView device[];

        try {
            URL url = new URL();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream())); 
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Log:

```
05-30 15:18:21.742: I/Choreographer(12300): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-30 15:18:22.305: I/ActivityManager(290): Displayed com.example.wip/.DevicesActivity: +2s340ms
05-30 15:18:23.992: I/System.out(12300): XML Pasing Excpetion = javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Also I got this message from Chrome when I try to see page info of the URL

```
the identity of this website has not been verified.• server's certificate is not trusted
```

Is this the website server's problem?  Can I fix it on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the server side.  It is using a bad certificate.  (According to firefox, the server's is not including the ticket issuer chain.  This is not even a self-signed certificate.  It is just misconfigured.)

> Can I fix it on my side?

You would need to add the server's certificate to your phone's keystore as a trusted certificate.  I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that? I want to give it a try to see if I can get the XML.

Comment: Using Keytool - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: If all you want is the XML, then download it using a web browser, telling the browser to use the bad certificate anyway.  But note that the server *also* requires a username and password.